# У чому полягає сенс використання слова "паляниця" для виявлення іноземців?

Tags: фонетика

Під час обговорення законопроектів про мову, користувачі у соцмережах [наводять](http://24tv.ua/tse_movniy_patrul_rozstrilyati_sotsmerezhi_obgovoryuyut_novi_zakonoproekti_pro_movu_n773827) такий анекдот:

> — Це мовний патруль! Пане, будь ласка, скажіть “паляниця”.
>   — Маца.
>   *(Обіймаються)*

У чому полягає сенс використання слова *паляниця* для виявлення іноземців?

Comment: Я тільки повернувся з Росії. У Владімірській області мене пригощали лісними ягодами. І кажуть: "А это лесная клубника. У нас она называется полуника".

Comment: @EagleZP73 з огляду на те, це точно не відповідь, я це перетворив на коментар.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Люди, котрі ніколи не вчили іноземну мову, думають, що добре володіють своїм мовленнєвим апаратом, але варто лише їм почати вивчати іншу мову, як вони зрозуміють, що вимова деяких звуків їм дається досить важко, а інколи взагалі не дається.

Виявляється, що у багатьох мовах існують звуки та звукосполуки, які дуже важко, а інколи зовсім неможливо, вимовити носіям деяких інших мов. Ця мовна особливість має назву **шібболе́т**. Докладніше про походження цього терміна можете прочитати у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%96%D0%B1%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82).

Попри те, що українська та російська мови мають багато спільного, є низка слів зі звуками, що складають труднощі для носія російської мови, котрий з малку не вчив українську. Ось ці слова: ***паляниця***, полуниця, криниця, рушниця тощо. Росіяни вимовляють це слово приблизно так "палянітса, паляница".

Цією мовною особливістю послуговувалися різні народи у різні часи, ось декілька загальновідомих шібболетів:

- Німцям важко вимовити російське слово "дорога", виходить "тарока".
- Американці на тихоокеанському фронті, для розрізнення японців від китайців, тайців та інших, використовували слово "lollapalooza", японці зовсім не вимовляють звук "л".
- Фіни ловили росіян за допомогою слова "Höyryjyrä", у рос. мові відсутні звуки Ö, Y, Ä, а R звучить також інакше.
- Англійці для пошуку німців послуговувалися словом "squirrel", бо німці казали "sqvirrel".

---

P.S. Якщо вам пощастить бути у складі мовного патруля, і у вас виникнуть проблеми з ідентифікацією росіянина за допомогою "*паляниці*", не впадайте у відчай, є ще один стовідсотковий тест — "*Миска вареників з картоплею та шкварками, змащених салом*" ;-)

Comment: "Миска вареників з картоплею та шкварками, змащених салом" — трішки не зрозумів: це треба з'їсти, чи вимовити?

Comment: От в чому тут "прикол" :D А я написав відповідь, зовсім не зрозумівши суті.

Comment: «Рос. слово „кукуруза“ (кукуґуза)» — [тут](http://marie-olshansky.ru/ct/zoo.shtml) пишуть «кукуружа»; часом, не знаєте, де правда?

Comment: Хм, дійсно незрозуміло, можливо йдеться про різні звуки, одні кажуть, що (укр.) кукурудза => кукуружа, а інші — (рос.)  кукуруза  => кукугуза". Відредагую відповідь.

Comment: Вся суть у кількох словах: в російській мові немає м’якої пари до Ц, тобто немає звука [tsʲ͡], замість нього росіяни вимовляють твердий [ts͡].

Comment: Один мій російськомовний знайомий невзмозі вимовити "жінка", у нього виходить "жинка", з твердим "ж". "'Жи'-'ши' пиши с 'и'", оце все.

Comment: Ще перевірочні слова і їх особливості: 
- "рябеньке телятко" — наявний унікального для мови м'якого звуку "и", до якого тяжіє "е" у слові "телятко".
- "попілнаста курочка" — тут м'яка "ч" у "курочці" не дасться так легко